# io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: ABORTED when using Grpc client in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, grpc, grpc-java

I'm trying to run a spark (2.2) job to get some data from the server using GRPC (1.1.2) client calls. I get this error when I run this code through spark. Running the same job for a small set works fine. From what I researched, I understand that ABORTED message is because of some concurrency issues, so I'm guessing it is because the client is unable to create more than a certain number of stubs, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Also, I know for a fact that the GRPC server works well with large number of requests and I'm well below the number of requests it can handle. Any ideas?

Adding more information as requested:
My client CatalogGrpcClient has these methods to handle channels and the request:

```
private List<ManagedChannel> getChannels() {
    return IntStream.range(0, numChannels).mapToObj(x ->
            ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(channelHost, channelPort).usePlaintext(true).build()
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private ManagedChannel getChannel() {
    return channels.get(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(channels.size()));
}

private ListingRequest populateRequest(ListingRequest.Builder req, String requestId) {
    return req.setClientSendTs(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setRequestId(StringUtils.defaultIfBlank(req.getRequestId(), requestId))
            .setSchemaVersion(StringUtils.defaultIfBlank(req.getSchemaVersion(), schema))
            .build();
}

private List<ListingResponse> getGrpcListingWithRetry(ListingRequest.Builder request,
                                                      String requestIdStr,
                                                      int retryLimit,
                                                      int sleepBetweenRetry) {
    int retryCount = 0;
    while (retryCount < retryLimit) {
        try {
            return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(CatalogServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(getChannel()).getListings(populateRequest(request, requestIdStr)), Spliterator.ORDERED), false).collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception " + e.getCause().getMessage());
            retryCount = retryCount + 1;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleepBetweenRetry);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    throw new StatusRuntimeException(Status.ABORTED);
}
```

I use the method getCatalogListingData in the method extract which is used to map to a case class in the spark job

```
def extract(itemIds: List[Long], validAspects: Broadcast[Array[String]]): List[ItemDetailModel] = {
    var itemsDetails = List[ItemDetailModel]()
    val client = new CatalogGrpcClient()
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    val listings = client.getCatalogListingData(itemIds.map(x => x.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Long]).asJava).asScala
    ...
    ...
    itemsDetails
}
```

Here's the spark code which calls extract. itemsMissingDetails is a dataframe with a column "item" which is a list of unique item ids. The zipWithIndex and the following map is so that I pass 50 item ids in each request to the GRPC svc.

```
itemsMissingDetails
  .rdd
  .zipWithIndex
  .map(x => (x._2 / 50, List(x._1.getLong(0))))
  .reduceByKey(_ ++ _)
  .flatMap(items => extract(items._2, validAspects))
  .toDF
  .write
  .format("csv")
  .option("header",true)
  .option("sep", "\t")
  .option("escapeQuotes", false)
  .save(path)
```

The ABORTED error is actually thrown by my client after a long time (~30 min to 1 hour). When I start this job, it gets the info I need from the GRPC svc for a few thousand items on every worker. After this, the job hangs up (on each worker) and after a really long wait (~30 min to 1 hour), it fails with the above exception or proceeds further. I haven't been able to consistently get StatusRuntimeException.

Comment: Show the relevant piece of code. How and where exactly do you execute the gRPC code?

Comment: Also show the message associated with the ABORTED error.

Comment: I have been facing the exact same issue